# Slight Confusion about Spherical Sector Definition

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

A book that I am reading defines the spherical sector as follows:

> A spherical sector is a solid generated by rotating a sector of a circle about an axis which passes through the center of the circle **but which contains no point inside the sector**.

I understood most of the definition except for the part indicated by the bold letters. The way I visualized how the spherical sector is formed is like this:

[image]

Clearly, some points of the axis of rotation are contained within the sector, which contradicts the statement "but which contains no point inside the sector." Am I missing something here?

Comment: The book is describing something like the region between two lines of latitude on the globe, whereas your picture is the region above a line of latitude extending clear to the pole. I would think both should be considered "sectors". why the book's definition specifically disallows the pole to be included I am not sure. Perhaps because that is also called a "spherical cap"?

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I came to the following conclusion which seems to satisfy the book's definition: if we only consider half of the 2d sector, then one complete revolution about the axis will form the spherical sector whereas if we take the full sector, then it would only take half a revolution to complete the 3d sector. And by considering only the half, the axis then lies on one of the radial sides of the 2d sector and thus it can be considered not within the sector

Comment: That makes sense. I was also interpreting it as the axis not intersecting the 2D sector at all, but the way it is worded, the axis can indeed be one of the border radii of the 2D sector. And by restricting the definition in this way, they can give a volume formula without worrying about double-sweeping.